# Leaflet draw polygon is rendering/drawn wrongly shifting bit away from selected position in Angular 17 with ssr enabled

Tags: angular, leaflet, rendering, polygon, leaflet.draw

We are using **angular 17** and we have used **leaflet and leaflet draw** JavaScript plugin to plot the map and want to draw polygons, rectangle over it and get the boundary co-ordinates of the same. But when we draw a polygon/rectangle it actually draws the polygon/rectangle at wrong position, slightly shifted from actual selected position(white boxes are actual position in the pic attached below).

[image: Leaflet with Angular 17]

Angular ssr is enabled. Does it create some issue. Please help me out in this

Html section

HTML code as below

```
<div class="row">
   <strong>Select the Area </strong>
     <div class="col-8">
        <div id="mapid"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Below is our component code

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
declare var L: any;
..
..
..
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let current_comp = this;
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      $(function () {
        current_comp.map = L.map('mapid', {}).setView([12.9834957, 77.5959527], 16);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(current_comp.map);
        var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();

        current_comp.map.addLayer(editableLayers);
        var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
          edit: {
            featureGroup: editableLayers,
            remove: true
          }, draw: {
            polyline: false,
            marker: false,
            circle: false,
            circlemarker: false
          }
        });
        // map.removeControl(drawControl);
        current_comp.map.addControl(drawControl);
     //   current_comp.map.addControl(drawControl);

        function makePopupContent(feature: any) {
          return feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
        }

        current_comp.map.on('draw:created', function (e: any) {
          var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;
          layer.setStyle({
            fillColor: '#0000CC', opacity: 0.1
          })
          var feature = layer.toGeoJSON();
          current_comp.boundary_co_ordinates = makePopupContent(feature);
          console.log(current_comp.boundary_co_ordinates);

          if (type === 'marker') {
            layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
          }

          editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
        });

        current_comp.map.on('draw:deleted', function (e: any) {
          console.log("Delete button is clicked");
          for (var i = 0; i < current_comp.markers_list.length; i++) {
            current_comp.map.removeLayer(current_comp.markers_list[i]);
            current_comp.map.removeLayer(current_comp.circle_list[i]);
          }
        })
      });
    }
  }
```